# Exclude file paths from a list based on contents of the files

Tags: mingw

I have a command that I execute that gives me a list of relative paths to files under a directory. Think in terms of using `find my_dir`, although the command itself is different.

For each file in the list, I want to pipe it into a command that will filter the list down depending on contents of the file itself. I'm looking for semantics identical or similar to `egrep -v` but it needs to open & read the file to run the regex on the file contents instead of the path itself.

How can I accomplish this using a simple piped command stream? Example:

```
find some_dir/ | egrep_contents -v 'Exclude pattern' | xargs -n1 do_something_with_filtered_files
```

In this case, `egrep_contents` is ideally the command I'm asking for in this question. It would run the specified exclude pattern on each line in the file until it finds a match. If a match is found, it prevents that file path from being passed down to the next piped command.

For context, I'm running these commands in Git Bash included with Git for Windows (MINGW).

Comment: Downvoters: Why?

Answer (score 0):

The `grep` option `--files-without-match` or `-L` may be what you're looking for. It tells grep to print out file paths whose corresponding file content does not match the given pattern. For example,

```
$ echo "bar" > foo
$ echo "quux" > baz

$ ls
baz foo

$ find . -type f | xargs -n1 grep -EL bar | xargs -n1 cat
quux
```

Here, "quux" is printed because it's the result of `cat` being run on the files whose contents do not contain "bar".